# AWS DynamoDB put item size limit exception for item size less than 400KB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

AWS DynamoDB limit for put item API call is 400KB. I am putting a Python dictionary, whose size is being calculated using `sys.getsizeof()` method. Even when the method returns value less than 400000 bytes, put item operation throws an exception:

`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size'`

Is there something that I am missing in terms of calculating the exact size?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have one or more [local secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.StorageConsiderations):

> The amount of space used by an index item is the sum of the following:
>
> - The size in bytes of the base table primary key (partition key and sort key)
> - The size in bytes of the index key attribute
> - The size in bytes of the projected attributes (if any)
> - 100 bytes of overhead per index item

And along with this note from [The DynamoDB limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html):

> For each local secondary index on a table, there is a 400 KB limit on the total of the following:
>
> - The size of an item's data in the table.
> - The size of the local secondary index entry corresponding to that item, including its key values and projected attributes.

In other words, you need to pad the size of each item, since the PutItem requires enough space for the item, and the index data, and the total of both of those needs to be less than 400kb.

Comment: After posting the question, I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768971/how-to-calculate-dynamodb-item-size-getting-validationerror-400kb-boto?rq=1, like as you indicated data is replicated for each index. Hence, the size calculation should account for extra LSI in the table.

Comment: Hey, I am having the same issue, the item exceeds 400kb(406kb exactly), how do I deal with it?